# Is there a shortcut for switching between drawing Lines and drawing Arcs in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I normally use AutoCAD for something like this.

I am digitizing parking lots and have to press the buttons on the toolbar to switch between lines and arcs while drawing.

Is there a shortcut that I can type rather than clicking the buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Customize in your main menu, then Toolbars, then Customize in that list. Now go to commands and wait for the GUI to populate. Go down to Editor and find the whatever tool you are using on the right and hit Keyboard on the bottom. Now find the tool again in the Customize Keyboard GUI (now that you know the name) and assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: +1, this is what I would have put in as an answer if I was awake at the time. I use Alt+a for arcs then Alt+s to switch back to drawing lines... Alt+v for edit tool, Alt+c for clear selection, Alt+r for merge. Customizable keyboard shortcuts make digitizing much quicker. Just remember you don't save much time if you have to take your hand off the mouse so I make all mine single left handed key combinations.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point. That's what I do with AutoCAD. It does make a big difference.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a construction tool active (e.g. line tool), you can also press TAB to display the feature construction toolbar at the mouse location then select a shape constructor.